# Откат миграции sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Вот файл миграции. В нем 2 таблицы, после первой прокидываю ошибку. По логике - должно откатить записанную первую таблицу, но этого не происходит. В чем может быть проблема? БД MySql

```
module.exports = {


 up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
let transaction;

try {
  transaction = await queryInterface.sequelize.transaction();

  await queryInterface.createTable('clients', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    countryCode: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    surname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    address: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    termsAndConditions: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: true,
    },
    avatarUrl: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    status: {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM(...Object.values(STATUSES)),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: STATUSES.new,
    },
    appId: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    approvalDate: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
    },
  }, {
    transaction,
    charset: config.get('define.charset'),
    collate: config.get('define.collate'),
  });

  throw new Error();

  await queryInterface.createTable('access_tokens', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    token: {
      type: Sequeldize.TEXT,
    },
    refreshToken: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    tokenExpiresAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
    status: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    clientId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'clients',
        key: 'id',
      },
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
    },
  }, {
    transaction,
    charset: config.get('define.charset'),
    collate: config.get('define.collate'),
  });

  await transaction.commit();
} catch (err) {
  logger.error({
    message: err,
    stackTrace: err.stack,
  });
  if (transaction) {
    await transaction.rollback();
  }
  throw err;
    }
  },
  down: async () => {
    logger.info('Sequelize down models');
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQl не поддерживает транзакции на создание, изменение и удаление таблиц!